# Transforming a linear program using a convex function into standard form

Tags: linear-programming, linearization

A paper that I am reading has a linear program of the following form:

$
\text{minimize}\ \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i) + c \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - x_{i - 1})^+
$

where $f_i$ is a non-negative convex function and $(\cdot)^+ := \text{max}\{0, \cdot\}$.

How can such a linear program be transformed into a standard form like:

$
\text{minimize}\ c^T x \\
\text{subject to} \\
Ax \leq b \\
x \geq 0
$

(for both integer and continuous linear programs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can linearize $f_i(x_i)$, but (assuming $c>0$) you can linearize the $(.)^+$ part by introducing nonnegative variables $y_i$, replacing the second sum in the objective with $c\sum_i y_i$, and imposing constraints $y_i \ge x_i - x_{i-1}$.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's non-linear. Thanks anyway! Transforming the second part in this way is a  nice idea :)